# I've show that a is true. How to show that rests are false?

Tags: metric-spaces

[image]

I've show that a is true. How to show that rests are false?

Comment: Given that you already know that a) is true, observe that then b) and c) are equivalent, so showing either of them false closes the case. Hint: find a sequence $f_n$ so that $d_2(f_n,0) \to 0$, but $d_1(f_n,0) \geqslant 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I want to say you that I really appreciate your nice comment(s). Thanks for sharing us your odd suggestions given for almost every questions. Wish to have them as independent answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

For (b): Having extremely different values on a very small range of inputs is enough to disrupt the sup norm, but not the integral norm.  Think about having a very steep line on $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$, going down to 0, then being 0 on $[\frac{1}{n},1]$.  How does this behave under the sup norm?  Under the integral norm?  It should have a limit under the integral norm that the sup norm can't agree with.

(c) You should be able to come up with this given (b).